# Magento theme implementation

Tags: magento

Hi I'm trying to figure out theme implementation in Magento. It's my first Magento Community Edition installation and obviously first theme that I try. Its a fairly popular theme called "Fortis". The problem I'm ecnoutering is when I click the links that is included in the default theme e.g. Account or Cart. The url link does not exist and its not included in the folders that comes with Fortis.

So my question is: What is the standard implementation when it comes to Magento Themes? What am I missing here and why are the links not working?

Fortis front page:

[image]

Links do not work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: try clearing/deleting cache

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems with the URL rewrite

try browsing to

```
localhost/magento_dev/public_html/index.php/hardvara.html
```

and

```
localhost/magento_dev/public_html/index.php/customer/account
```

1. Check your .htaccess for RewriteBase and set it accordingly
2. Enable Web Server rewrites at Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization
3. Clear Cache.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, you should try to access/install magento using your IP address instead of localhost. It should be something like that `http://192.168.1.123/magento_dev`. Replace this dummy ip with your own ip address.